# Can ndb be used simultaneously with Java datastore access?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

We are developing an AppEngine app that is written partly in Java, partly in Python (different versions use different languages). 
I am wondering if I can use the ndb database on the Python side, to access some models that are shared with the Java code.

Specifically, when an entity is updated from the Java side, is the ndb cached value for that entity invalidated automatically?  Obviously, this would be essential, otherwise ndb would return the previous value.

Furthermore, if a write commits (returns) in ndb, is the value available immediately on the Java side when retrieving by key?  I read that an ndb write returns once the cache is invalidated, which would not guarantee that the data is retrievable by key from the Java side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suspect, since the Java Datastore API doesn't know about NDB's cache, you'd have to turn off that cache if you want your Python code to see changes made by the Java process immediately.  It's possible to turn off the cache only for specific requests (e.g. key.get(use_memcache=False)) or only for a specific model (add _use_memcache = False as a class variable).

There is no problem with Java seeing changes made through NDB.  I don't know where you read that, but it is not true that NDB returns before the data is written through to the Datastore (unless you use an async write and never wait for the response -- but even so the infrastructure will wait for the write to succeed before returning an HTTP response to the user).

The actual sequence of events on a write is as follows:

1. lock the memcache entry by writing a special value to it
2. write the data to the Datastore
3. invalidate the memcache entry by deleting it

(The memcache entry is brought up to date by the next read.)

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.  I was wondering whether there was a ndb cache-invalidation mechanism implemented in the infrastructure used also by Java.  In my case, I will probably do an ndb get without using memcache as you suggest every so often, frequently enough so that the use of stale data between such gets is acceptable for my purposes.

Comment: Actually, I still have a question.  When I read with .get(use_memcache=False), does this update the memcache with the value in the datastore, or does it bypass the memcache, leaving stale values in the memcache unchanged?

Comment: That bypasses memcache completely.

Comment: Thus, if I write to a model also from the Java side, I cannot use ndb with caching -- I cannot even do a call from Java to my Python code to cause ndb to update its cache.  It seems the only solution is to use the normal db interface, and do the caching in ad-hoc fashion using memcache.

Comment: You can use ndb fine, just disable the caching.  You can also use ndb for ad hoc caching using use_datastore=false, use_memcace=True.